# remove runFullTrust capability from flutter Windows application

Tags: flutter, windows

I have developed a windows application in flutter. it seems to be a Win32 app by default and it includes "runFullTrust" capability in it by default and my application doesn't need this capability. i have tried many ways to remove this capability but i failed to do so. i am building msix of application with msix flutter package.

when publishing the app on microsoft store it says your app includes runFullTrust capability, give some solid reasons why you have included it. so as my app doesn't need this particular capability it is making a hurdle for me. can anyone tell me how to remove this capability from my code?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I've just published my flutter app to the Microsoft Store with the same warning.
I provided the following explanation to the reviewer:

*"This app was built using Flutter.
There is no way to change this setting.
Flutter builds win32 apps in this way using an official msix dart package."*

And it looks like it worked. The app is now with status "**In the Microsoft Store**" and link does work, app is visible.